# No module named 'huggingface_hub.snapshot_download'

Tags: python, huggingface

When I try to run the [quick start notebook](https://github.com/yangkevin2/emnlp22-re3-story-generation#quick-start-with-notebook) of [this repo](https://github.com/yangkevin2/emnlp22-re3-story-generation), I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huggingface_hub.snapshot_download'`. How can I fix it? I already installed `huggingface_hub` using pip.

I get the error after compiling the following cell:

```
!CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python -u ../scripts/main.py --summarizer gpt3_summarizer --controller longformer_classifier longformer_classifier --loader alignment coherence --controller-load-dir emnlp22_re3_data/ckpt/relevance_reranker emnlp22_re3_data/ckpt/coherence_reranker --controller-model-string allenai/longformer-base-4096 allenai/longformer-base-4096 --save-outline-file output/outline0.pkl --save-complete-file output/complete_story0.pkl --log-file output/story0.log
```

Here's the entire output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../scripts/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from story_generation.edit_module.entity import *
  File "/home/jovyan/emnlp22-re3-story-generation/story_generation/edit_module/entity.py", line 20, in <module>
    from story_generation.common.util import *
  File "/home/jovyan/emnlp22-re3-story-generation/story_generation/common/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .evaluation import SentenceEvaluator
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/evaluation/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .InformationRetrievalEvaluator import InformationRetrievalEvaluator
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/evaluation/InformationRetrievalEvaluator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..util import cos_sim, dot_score
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/util.py", line 407, in <module>
    from huggingface_hub.snapshot_download import REPO_ID_SEPARATOR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huggingface_hub.snapshot_download'
```

Comment: Fixed using `pip install huggingface-hub==0.10.1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of `sentence-transformers` fixes it (no need to install `huggingface-hub` explicitly):

```
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```

I've proposed [a pull request](https://github.com/yangkevin2/emnlp22-re3-story-generation/pull/5) for this in the original repo.